# How do I list all containers in a user-defined docker network?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-network

How do I get a list of all the containers in a user-defined docker network?

I would like to get all the commit hashes of every container for a specific user-defined docker network.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
docker network inspect \
  -f '{{ range $key, $value := .Containers }}{{ printf "%s\n" $key}}{{ end }}' \
  <network-id>
```

will give a newline delimited list of the container hashes belonging to the `network-id` network.

You can adjust the `printf` format to get other syntax (comma-separated, tab-separated, container id+name, etc). For example:

```
 $ docker network inspect \
    -f '{{ range $key, $value := .Containers }}{{printf "%s: %s\n" $key .Name}}{{ end }}' \
    web-ingress
0b7f82ad7535ac7c1a454aaf0a5df6b87547d3cb9d751d0e0e1b4952a849b11b: mon_grafana.1.v5i0ea6nv12k0h3eo8egglg6n
1cce723642af2ce9382c7d46cca868d4674b4645d07458eeed9e928d29a4fb1f: mon_prometheus.1.lsfdcig6uhqfbbv7n07irpj3j
1f4840710f77fa1e02bd3e95581139b9f3c13fe4c857ce6ac44bfbdae4916920: mon_alertmanager.1.kwvw7kqsfpi9qzpmqdrd85yc7
2efea443fee41fd5dbca714145ca6ff95d91be9c60a469be597aadfaca90914d: mon_unsee.1.3lg8qgnvshibklnypzt5rw95s
6fdb893488f6e56766501e763d4c60196ae12a22ee9bd204d84fe324331714e8: mon_dashboard.1.r6b6nhatwmk88y5ncgagnaxh4
lb-web-ingress: web-ingress-endpoint
```

Answer (score 23):

You can list all networks with:

```
docker network ls
```

And inspect one network to see its hosts (containers)

```
docker network inspect <network-id>
```

Inspecting that a container, you can see which network it is connected to:

```
docker inspect <container-id>
```

More info in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#create-networks

Comment: I found that when a container has been brought up with an attribute of 
network_mode:  "service: <some service name>"

that the 'docker inspect' or 'docker network inspect ' commands are not going to give you the information as detailed above.

What you will see is something like this:
"NetworkMode": "container: <some container id representing the service>"

Answer (score 2):

A simple command to list the names of the container using a custom network is:

```
docker inspect network-name | grep Name
```

This command will list the name of the network and containers connected to it like below:

```
"Name": "network-name",
        "Name": "Container1",
        "Name": "Container2",
```

Comment: Actually this should be `docker network inspect network-name | grep Name`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using pure bash and no python - easier to remember for me

```
docker network inspect YOUR_NETWORK_ID | grep Name | tail -n +2 | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ',"'
```

Sample output

```
container1
container2
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be simple as below as well. To list name of the container only

```
docker network inspect NETWORK ID | grep "Name" | awk -F":" '{print $2}' | tr -d ',"'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my bash command using [python's json parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/248616)

```
docker network inspect YOUR_NETWORK_ID \
    | python -c "import sys, json; print([v['Name'] for k,v in json.load(sys.stdin)[0]['Containers'].items()])"
```

Sample output

```
[u'container1', u'container2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when a container has been brought up with an attribute of

`network_mode:  "service: <some service name>"`

that the 'docker inspect' or 'docker network inspect ' commands are not going to give you the information as detailed above.

What you will see instead is something like this:

`"NetworkMode": "container: <some container id representing the service>"`

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to contribute with another way of obtaining the result, still using `docker network inspect`, but providing other possibilities in terms of data inspection and output format.

---

You list the available networks for Docker:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME          DRIVER    SCOPE
a1682358dfa3   bridge        bridge    local
c6910d1da750   host          host      local
c9790e542025   none          null      local
9b265ecb4042   web_default   bridge    local
```

You inspect the network, with output in JSON, accessing the **Containers** object + prettifying the JSON:

```
$ docker network inspect web_default -f '{{json .Containers}}' | python3 -m json.tool
{
    "5d05c2606b022b0c9bc480f138b8f8f0e382dca4b1decb1c27181a66e641803f": {
        "Name": "django",
        "EndpointID": "b6bf6b1dc5437f2359fb550368a5bc6529cd80fa5b9ece3c752eecef6627ea57",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
        "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "b971715bd0b3560831b03e86bcf2151ed04a60a46ad90b24f1f2265617360344": {
        "Name": "postgres",
        "EndpointID": "5883f465e235c66327271c1dfd05372f02012efa78928dd447c5444b0468647c",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
        "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    }
}
```

You can even redirect the command output to a for further inspection:

```
$ docker network inspect web_default -f '{{json .Containers}}' | python3 -m json.tool > web_default_containers.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most elegant solution I could come up with:

```
docker inspect test -f '{{range.Containers}}{{println .Name}}{{end}}' | awk NF
```

The extra `awk` call is to remove the annoying empty line at the end.