# how to view all domains in a docker network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a network in docker filled with containers. Some are unnamed and can be found by ip. Others are named and can be accessed with a dns lookup.

How do I view all the resolvable domains in a docker network? If it's not possible to view all, how to view all the domains which reach a certain container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all containers in a user-defined docker network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724764/how-do-i-list-all-containers-in-a-user-defined-docker-network)

Comment: No, domains and containers are not the same. In certain situations, they are related - but I'm not looking for indications of my containers on a network. I'm explicitly looking for domains ( not ip ) registered with the dns server

Answer (score 1):

In a default bridge network containers can access each other [by IP](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services). In a user-defined bridge network they can also use [names and aliases](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge). Additionally you can specify a network explicitly (`name-or-alias` -> `name-or-alias.network`).

To list aliases in a network:

```sh
for c in `docker ps -q`; do \
    docker inspect "$c" \
        -f $'{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{$k}} {{.Aliases}}\n{{end}}'; \
done | awk '$1 == "<network>"'
```

Output:

```
<network> [<alias1> <alias2>...]
...
```

E.g.:

```
prj_default [app 59bb8a265b9b]
...
```

To list container names and aliases across all networks:

```sh
for c in `docker ps -q`; do \
    echo -n "`docker inspect "$c" -f '{{.Name}}'` ($c): "; \
    docker inspect "$c" \
        -f '{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{$k}} {{.Aliases}} {{end}}'; \
done
```

Output:

```
/<container_name> (<container_id>): <network1> [<alias1> <alias2>...] <network2> [<alias1> <alias2>...]...
...
```

E.g.:

```
/prj_app_1 (59bb8a265b9b): prj_default [app 59bb8a265b9b]
...
```

To check what a domain resolves to in a container:

```
$ getent hosts app
192.168.224.5     app  app
```

To list name and aliases of a specific container:

```sh
docker inspect 59bb8a265b9b \
    -f '{{.Name}} {{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{$k}} {{.Aliases}} {{end}}'
```

More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/b1c6cb8da60f799cf7d46b7b38b65a2d).