# How do I use ansible docker modules to list all containers in a specific docker network

Tags: list, docker, networking, ansible

How can I use docker ansible modules to list all containers in a specific network?
I would like to accomplish this without using ansible `shell` commands.

Is this possible?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724764/how-do-i-list-all-containers-in-a-user-defined-docker-network) which would work if I used `shell` commands. But again, I dont want to do that. How can I do with docker ansible modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`community.docker.docker_network_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_network_info_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-network-info-module) module to inspect the network; the returned information includes a list of containers attached to the network.

For example, this playbook will display a list of containers attached to the network name in the `docker_network` variable:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    docker_network: bridge
  collections:
    - community.docker
  tasks:
    - name: "get network info"
      docker_network_info:
        name: "{{ docker_network }}"
      register: net_info

    - name: "get container info"
      docker_container_info:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      register: container_info
      loop: "{{ net_info.network.Containers.keys() }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ container_info.results|json_query('[].container.Name') }}"
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply on this, this works, however it only lists active containers. Is there a way to list all containers using the network, even if they are in an existed status?

Comment: Nm, there is no way to do that with these modules. I will accept this as the correct answer. Thanks!