# List all IP addresses of Docker containers from different machines connected to an overlay network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

I want to run a distributed computation inside Docker containers over multiple physical machines. To be as independent from the surrounding environment as possible, I create a Docker swarm and an overlay network `my-net`, and then run docker containers with the `--network=my-net` option. This way, the applications within the containers can do cross-node communication over the overlay network. However, my application require a list of IP addresses of all computation nodes, i.e., the IP address of all containers connected to the overlay network.

I can use `docker network inspect my-net` to find out all containers connected to my network *on the current machine*. But it doesn't include the other machines. How is it possible to find out this information?

Note 1: Tools like `nmap` (scan for IP addresses) can be a solution to my problem, but not applicable here because my machines are located in a monitored cloud environment with "security scanners" that could identify the use of such tools as dangerous behavior and isolate my machines.

Note 2: There exist similar questions on StackOverflow already, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724764/how-do-i-list-all-containers-in-a-user-defined-docker-network), but I haven't found any solution for multiple machines or Docker swarms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any container attached to my-net thats using the default container dns (127.0.0.11) can get the IP address of any other container on the network using "hostname", "container-id", "container_name" "hostname.my-net", "id.my-net" and "container.my-net".

If the container is running as service, then the service name can be used (also with or without the network suffix) to return the ip of a virtual IP that load balances connections amongst service tasks, and "tasks.{service}" returns a dnsrr response with all the IPs.

If the target is a service deployed as part of a stack then "{stack}_" can prefix service names.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So, `ping ${container_id}` and `ping ${container_name}` do give me the IP address of the other container(s). In order to get the IP addresses of all workers, I simply need to give the containers predictable names (such as `worker-1`, `worker-2`, ...), and on the main node iterate over these names.